# Spark DataFrame change datatype based on JSON value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm constructing a dataframe from a JSON file and saving this dataframe to a parquet file. This parquet file is consumed by a PIG script for further processing.
Below is the schema of the JSON file:

```
{id:"1",
 name:"test",
 "fields": [
        {
            "fieldId": "ABC1.0",
            "values": [
                {
                    "key": "812320",
                    "formId": 11100,
                    "occ": 1,
                    "attachId": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldId": "CDE2.0",
            "values": [
                {
                    "key": "MA",
                    "formId": 11100,
                    "occ": 1,
                    "attachId": 0
                },
                {
                    "key": 23.0,
                    "formId": 11100,
                    "occ": 1,
                    "attachId": 0
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

I need to set the data type of the "key" field based on its value. The value of the key could be string, long double, integer.
How Can I achieve this using spark dataframe/dataset.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to specify multiple types for a single column in a same dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your content in the json file is wrong. All properties need to be enclosed in double quotes :-

[image]